# Are there any REST service automation frameworks?

Tags: java, rest

We want to expose our data over REST based services using simple HTTP GET/POST request, So that clients will be able to send queries over REST based API and response will be returned in JSON/XML format.
Are there any automation frameworks where I can define Input and Output format and framework will generate basic send/receive modules ( in Java or any other language ) with blank boxes for business logic ?

Update:
I just read about [Play Framework](http://www.playframework.org/),

I think,
Jersey + JPA would be better option for faster REST service development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some search, I found [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/) with Jackson could automate building REST services upto certain extent

There are also other options,

Spring DATA,
Spring Rookie but they consider JPA for database.